# docker buildx armv7 platform missing

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi4, buildx

I am trying to build a docker image for a raspberry pi 4 (linux/arm/v7). I am using Ubuntu WSL. I have been able to build the image for Ubuntu WSL with no issues.
I am using docker buildx to build the image for raspberry pi4 (armv7). I created the builder like this:

```
docker buildx create --name my_builder
```

But listing the builder it looks that the armv7 is missing along with other platforms. Any idea how is this possible? does Ubuntu WSL doesnt support this cross platform? Would I need to do this directly from Windows or some other host platform?

```
> docker buildx inspect
Name:   my_builder
Driver: docker-container

Nodes:
Name:      my_builder0
Endpoint:  unix:///var/run/docker.sock
Status:    running
Platforms: linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/386
```

In case this help:

```
> docker buildx ls
NAME/NODE                 DRIVER/ENDPOINT             STATUS                 PLATFORMS
my_builder *              docker-container
  my_builder0 unix:///var/run/docker.sock             running                linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/386
desktop-linux                                         protocol not available
default                   docker
  default                 default                     running                linux/amd64, linux/386
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be possible by installing QEMU

```
sudo apt-get install -y qemu qemu-user-static
```

After that you should have more architectures/platforms to build images for.